# Searching an array of users for distinguished name

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to search an array of users and separate the array into two lists based on the name not containing a value but I am getting the users that still contain the string I search for.

I am supposed to search AD for disabled users and separate them based on their name.

I tried the following:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -ne $True}

foreach ($user in $users) {
    $user.Name | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne "Slack*"}
}
```

I should see a separate list of users where their name has "Slack*" in it.

Comment: you are using `-ne` with a wildcard. that operator DOES NOT use wildcards. [*grin*] i suspect you should use `-like` since that one DOES use wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for. It will pull all users that are disabled and then create a filtered list of what you are looking for

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Users = @(
    Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false}
)

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Filtered_Users = @(
    $Users | Where-Object { $_.Name -notmatch "Slack" }
)

foreach ($User in $Filtered_Users) {
    $Users.Remove($User)
}
```

`-ne` will look for an exact match

`-notmatch` should return everything that doesn't contain what you filter by

`-match` will show you what you filter by

EDITED to add example to remove from `$Users`

Comment: `-notlike 'Slack*'` would be more appropriate here. `-notmatch 'Slack'` will produce all results that don't contain the string "Slack" anywhere rather than those that don't begin with "Slack". You could use `-notmatch '^Slack'`, but wildcard operators are better performance-wise, so they're preferable unless you actually need a regular expression match.

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way to do this with an if statement where i could match the pattern to "Slack" and remove the items found and put them into a new array?

Comment: I am not sure of a way with an if statement that won't break the loop. I edited to show a way though.